# Rainbow animation in batch file

Tags: batch-file

(If you don't understand the "rainbow color changing animation",i basically want it to change the text foreground color to rainbow.

If you still don't understand what i am saying because my english is garbage,Please watch this C++ rainbow changing video:https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OKxxgozO3pE)

So,i am trying to make a batch TUI (text user interface) and i want to make the UI have a rainbow changing color animation.

Now,I have tried using this batch code:

```
:loop
For /L %%A IN (0,1,8) DO color 0%%A
Goto loop
```

The script above (kinda) did make a rainbow color changing animation.But the
problem is that the color change way too fast make it look like a big messy color mixer.

I did one thing:Is to use the ping -n trick.But it still look weird.

```
Ping -n 1 > nul
```

Make an absolutely no difference at all.

```
Ping -n 2 > nul
```

Make slow motion animation that just look boring.

So,i was wondering,is there any type of batch command,External program,plugin or anyway to archive rainbow changing color animation?

(I think that only using pure batch is impossible.But i could be wrong.)

Comment: Windows 10 can use [VT100 escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) to set colors and cursor positions, but older versions can't. You also haven't even remotely described what you want the animation to look like other than "smooth" and "rainbow" (both of which are fairly meaningless), so answering this question is impossible.

Comment: You are on the right track with `/n 2`, because you don't want the ping time but the wait time between pings. `ping`'s default wait time is 1000ms (1 second), but you can change it with the `/w` parameter (see `ping /?`

Comment: Seeing people saying this is impossible,I have removed "smooth" because that prove nothing at all.